# Is there a way to change the blank screen color that comes before Splash screen based on the Apps theme?

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen, android-theme

I want to change the Blank screen background colour based on app theme for eg. if app theme is in light mode then it should come with white background. and if app theme is dark theme then it should come with black background it should not be based on device theme.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Does this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/69386585/11983124

Comment: And you can't change the color of the background, according to the saved preference of the user. you can only set a default color.

Answer (score 5):

In your base application theme, add item `android:windowBackground` and set it's value to your desired color.

> Here's an example

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Other theme customizations -->


    <!-- Add this line and set value to your desired color -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorBlack</item>
</style>
```